# JBPM 6.1.0 kie workbench not working - Did not find a way to clear Weld's event observer cache.

Tags: jbpm, weld, errai, kie, kie-workbench

I downloaded JBPM 6.1.0 and followed the installation steps and started the demo using "ant start.demo". The server started fine.

But when I tried accessing the KIE workbench, the UI does not work or come up for most of the links. I find the below error in the server logs.

Did not find a way to clear Weld's event observer cache. Some CDI events may be undeliverable to clients. Problematic BeanManagerImpl is class org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@5a394295

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Selvam S

Comment: Is that the only error that you can see?

Answer (score 0):

I made sure I deleted the "jbpm-installer" folder and downloaded the
full version (jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full.zip) and it worked:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/jBPM%206/jbpm-6.1.0.Final/